# How can I install a specific versio of solc?

Tags: ubuntu, version, ethereum, solidity

My system is ubuntu 20.04, and I want to instalk the solc0.4.15,but I can find the package,if there has some sugesstion for me, I would very very very thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most pain-free way to run different Solidity versions is through Docker:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/installing-solidity.html#docker

I made a little shell script to help in this:

https://gist.github.com/miohtama/03e2eafa349474042675b44ca519af96